# What happens to the footballs used throughout a tournament?

Tags: football, trivia

I was thinking what happens to the balls used during a tournament.

Lets say the 2014 FIFA world cup. What happens to all the Brazuca balls used throughout the tournament? Where and in what ways are these balls used?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The balls were given away to the marketing teams for each country, and encouraged to give them away. Most will probably end up in museums or executive's offices but a few may well be given away.

“The balls are used after a tournament for souvenirs for the teams and referees, host cities, Fifa partners and the Fifa museum,” a Fifa spokesperson told us.

See http://www.theguardian.com/football/2014/jul/23/what-happens-to-world-cup-balls